# HTML entities showing in deleted user's name

Tags: bug, encoding, deleted-accounts

Take a look at the asker's username here:
[Case insensitive string replacement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280793/case-insensitive-string-replacement-in-javascript)

[image: Antti Sykäri]

Comment: Works fine for [non-deleted users](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2948/antti-sykari).